# How to use UIPreviewParameters to specify a range of text as a highlighted preview for UIContextMenuInteraction without hiding the rest of the view?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uicontextmenuinteraction, uipointerinteraction

**Update for iOS 13.4 (March, 2020):**

This also happens with `UIPointerInteraction` when hovering over the links.

---

I have a view that displays rich text and shows the iOS 13 context menu when the user long presses on a link. I want to be able to highlight just the link rather than the whole view when the user begins to long press.

To do this I provide a `UITargetedPreview` object that contains `UIPreviewParameters` with the `CGRect`s of each line to be highlighted to the `UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate` of the view. This correctly highlights the link, **but has the unwanted side effect of also hiding the rest of the view**.

This image demonstrates the problem:

[image]

Notice that, while the link is highlighted correctly, the remainder of the view flashes in and out as the link is long pressed and then released.

Compare this to the behaviour in Apple's own Notes.app:

[image]

Notice that the rest of the view does not disappear when a link is long pressed. This also works as expected in Apple's other apps, too (e.g. Safari).

---

I provide `UITargetedPreview`s to the interaction delegate in the following way:

```swift
func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, previewForHighlightingMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
    guard let range = configuration.identifier as? NSRange else { return nil }        
    let lineRects: [NSValue] = // calculate appropriate rects for the range of text
    let parameters = UIPreviewParameters(textLineRects: lineRects)
    return UITargetedPreview(view: /* the rich text view */, parameters: parameters)
}

func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, previewForDismissingMenuWithConfiguration configuration: UIContextMenuConfiguration) -> UITargetedPreview? {
    guard let range = configuration.identifier as? NSRange else { return nil }        
    let lineRects: [NSValue] = // calculate appropriate rects for the range of text
    let parameters = UIPreviewParameters(textLineRects: lineRects)
    return UITargetedPreview(view: /* the rich text view */, parameters: parameters)
}
```

I can't find anything in what documentation there is for [`UITargetedPreview`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitargetedpreview) and [`UIPreviewParameters`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipreviewparameters), so does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I finally found out how to do it thanks to [an implementation in WebKit](https://github.com/qtwebkit/webkit-mirror/blob/9db02519b2a2e729077bcec1016f9910be0f46c1/Source/WebKit/UIProcess/ios/WKContentViewInteraction.mm#L8649). What I was doing wrong was not providing the targeted preview a `UIPreviewTarget`.

To highlight only a portion of a view you need to:

1. Provide UIPreviewParameters stating the portion of the view to show in the preview, and set the background colour to the same as the view you want to preview
2. Provide a [UIPreviewTarget](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipreviewtarget) that establishes:

   - the whole view as the container of the animation
   - the centre of the portion being shown as the centre of the animation
3. [Create a snapshot](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622597-resizablesnapshotview) of the portion of the view you want to show and designate it as view of the [UITargetedPreview](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/UITargetedPreview).

In code this looks like:

```swift
let view: UIView = // the view with the context menu interaction
let highlightedRect: CGRect = // the rect of the highlighted portion to show

// 1        
let previewParameters = UIPreviewParameters()
previewParameters.visiblePath = // path of highlighted portion of view to show, remember you can use UIPreviewParameters.init(textLineRects:) for text
previewParameters.backgroundColor = view.backgroundColor

// 2: Notice that we're passing the whole view in here
let previewTarget = UIPreviewTarget(container: view, center: CGPoint(x: highlightedRect.midX, y: highlightedRect.midY))

// 3: Notice that we're passing the snapshot view in here - not the whole view
let snapshot = view.resizableSnapshotView(from: highlightedRect, afterScreenUpdates: true, withCapInsets: .zero)!
return UITargetedPreview(view: snapshot, parameters: previewParameters, target: previewTarget)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is super helpful. I used hitTest to detect the highligted view and I am glad about the results, so just wanted to share.

```html
- (UITargetedPreview *)contextMenuInteraction:(UIContextMenuInteraction *)interaction previewForHighlightingMenuWithConfiguration:(UIContextMenuConfiguration *)configuration {    
    UIView *view = interaction.view;
    CGPoint location = [interaction locationInView:view];
    // Detecting the hittable subview at the given location
    UIView *subView = [view hitTest:location withEvent:nil];
    if (subView) {
        CGRect highlightedRect = subView.frame;
        UIPreviewParameters *previewParameters = [UIPreviewParameters new];
        previewParameters.backgroundColor = subView.backgroundColor;
        previewParameters.visiblePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, highlightedRect.size.width, highlightedRect.size.height)];

        return [[UITargetedPreview alloc] initWithView:subView parameters:previewParameters];
    }
    return nil;
}
```